# Create newest version of SQLLocalDB, but version mismatch

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I need the newest version of SQL LocalDB so I can use `STRING_AGG` function.

After trying to download and install LocalDB from SQL Server 2017 Express Installer I have these versions:

[image]

But when I check available versions it gives:

[image]

Finlly if I create new instance with `sqllocaldb create "TestInstance"`, expecting to create it with the newest version, the result is `11.x`:

[image]

How can I create 2017 instance of LocalDB so I can use `STRING_AGG` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a [known bug in SQL Server 2016 SP1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1257bf26-6ab0-416d-bf26-34f128f42248/sql-2016-sp1-sqllocaldb-versions-errors-with-windows-api-call-reggetvaluew-returned-error-code). It still hasn't been fixed yet, though.

To repeat the solution presented there for posterity: if the registry value

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion
```

has the value `13.1.xxxx.x` (where `x` is anything) then

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions\13.0
```

should be renamed to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions\13.1
```

at which point the `sqllocaldb` utility should work again (and should pick the latest version installed if no parameters are supplied to `create`, but if you can always force things with `c "database" 14.0`).

Comment: It works ! Thanks for referencing this bug fix in a brief manner. Now I see the latest versions with `sqllocaldb v`. By default it creates again with -v `11.x`, but when you force it with `14.0` it's fine.

Comment: Thank you! After changing this in the registry, <code>sqllocaldb v</code> shows all the installed versions again. +1